# header_image() not displaying in custom theme

Tags: php, wordpress, image, wordpress-theming

I made a custom theme locally for woocommerce but after I upload it I have the following problem:

My main page has a header image (taken from the featured image) and I use the following code to get that image:

```
    <div class="header-content background-image" style="background-image: url(<?php header_image(); ?>);">
    </div>
```

When I run this locally, everything is working as it should and wordpress gets the featured image and displays it on my homepage.

But after I uploaded it, the image isn't getting pulled and when I inspect the element where it should be it reads:

```
<div class="header-content background-image" style="background-image: url();">
</div>
```

So somehow it's not getting any url.

Can anyone help me with this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Edit the file functions.php inside your theme and add the following code

```
register_default_headers( array(
    'wheel' => array(
        'url'           => '%s/images/headers/wheel.jpg',
        'thumbnail_url' => '%s/images/headers/wheel-thumbnail.jpg',
        'description'   => __( 'Wheel', 'twentyeleven' )
    ),
    'shore' => array(
        'url'           => '%s/images/headers/shore.jpg',
        'thumbnail_url' => '%s/images/headers/shore-thumbnail.jpg',
        'description'   => __( 'Shore', 'twentyeleven' )
    ),
    'trolley' => array(
        'url'           => '%s/images/headers/trolley.jpg',
        'thumbnail_url' => '%s/images/headers/trolley-thumbnail.jpg',
        'description'   => __( 'Trolley', 'twentyeleven' )
    )
) );
```

I hope this helps you.